# How to add custom cards in jquery.payment library

Tags: jquery

I use this [plugin](https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment) for credit cards. And I want to add custom card with 19 digits length. I don't know how to do that and I did not find any resource while searching. Please help me how to use $.payment.cards. Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqztoxej/). I tried using like that

```
$.payment.cards.push({
            // Card type, as returned by $.payment.cardType.
            type: 'mastercard',
            // Array of prefixes used to identify the card type.
            patterns: [
              51, 52, 53, 54, 55,
              22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27
            ],
            // Array of valid card number lengths.
            length: [19],
            // Array of valid card CVC lengths.
            cvcLength: [3],
            // Boolean indicating whether a valid card number should satisfy the Luhn check.
            luhn: true,
            // Regex used to format the card number. Each match is joined with a space.
            format: /(\d{1,4})/g
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is I had to use `unshift` method rather than `push`.

> Hi there [@SerikK](https://github.com/SerikK). You can use custom cards with 19 digits. Your pattern is being masked by another pattern (they are selected in order). You want to use more-specific patterns and use unshift rather than push.

– *You can see original answer made by author [here](https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment/issues/239).*